# Can't connect Socket to ServerSocket using two PCs in different networks

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

### Description

The goal is to have a Server run in my computer while another person runs a Client at their computer, in a different network

This should be done using the `Socket` and `ServerSocket` classes from the `java.net` packgage.

**Expected output** is a connection between Server and Client

**Actual output** is no connection

#### Source code:

Note: The bare minimum amount of code required for the connection is provided, stripped of unnecessary print/log statements, and other code to make the UI/application function as intented.

Server.java:

```
class Server {
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket connection;
    final int PORT = 0xface    // random port

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server application = new Server();    // constructor is just for UI
        application.runServer();
    }

    private runServer() {
        server = new ServerSocket(PORT, 5);
        connection = server.accept();
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
class Client {
    String charServerAddress;
    final int PORT = 0xface    // random port, same as Server port

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client application = new Client(args[0]);  // where args[0] is 127.0.0.1
        application.runClient();
    }
    
    public Client(String host) {chatServerAddress = host;}

    private runClient() {
        client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(chatServerAddress), PORT);
    }
}
```

#### Result

Server runs normally, but Client can't connect

#### Before arriving to the problem

1. Client connecting to localhost, that is, using `127.0.0.1` as argument in `client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(chatServerAddress), PORT)`.

   - Things work as expected; Client can connect to Server.
2. Client connecting using the IP address of the Server, *server run on same machine as client*. We got the IP Address of the Server by typing `ipconfig` on cmd on the machine hosting it, then using the `IPv4 Address`.

   - Things work as expected; Client can connect to Server.
3. Client connecting using the IP address of the Server, *server and client run on different machines*. We got the IP Address of the Server typing `ipconfig` on cmd on the machine hosting it, then using the `IPv4 Address`.

   - **Problem**: No Error message, however the client never connected to the server.

#### Solutions attempted

1. Disabling windows firewall completely on both machines.
2. Switching which machine hosts Server and which is Client.
3. Using different `PORT` number.
4. Pinging one machine from the other by typing `ping <IP Address>` in cmd.

All of the above resulted in the same error: `connection timeout`.

Comment: any firewall settings? are both located in the same network? ah, you mentioned that the networks are different, then is the destination node's address public?

Comment: @mangusta When viewing all firewall rules Java did have some access blocked. However, our first solution was to completely disable it on both machines, which didn't work. Yes, the Server and the Client are on different networks

Comment: How are the networks connected?

Comment: @NomadMaker I don't think they are, I am connected to the internet via router via my ISP and the other guy is at his home, miles away, connected to the internet via his router via a possibly different ISP.

Comment: Does the computer at your home have an external ip-name? Otherwise, how do you find the ip-number to connect to it?